# The action of attaching

Tags: word-meaning

The word "attachment" describes the thing, which gets attached. But can the word also be used for the action of attaching? If not which noun would fit better? If I want to explicitly distinguish between the thing which gets attached and the action of attaching which words should I use?

Comment: For stage actors, the attachment of a false moustache to the upper lip, using glue, is a quick task, but the removal may be painful .

Comment: `If I want to explicitly distinguish between the thing which gets attached and the action of attaching which words should I use?` -- can you try to give an example of a sentence in which you're doing such a thing? I think I could help you from there, but it's hard to imagine what you might be trying to say.

Comment: @TKoL The attachment of the attachment is mandatory. In German we have two words: one for the object and one for the action. I am wondering if there are also two words in English.

Comment: [A dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attachment) will explain that attachment can refer to the action, the thing which is attached, or a thing which provides a connection between two other things. A thesaurus will provide alternatives, but it will depend on what kind of thing you're attaching (it helps if you give a specific example where you want to use the word).

Comment: "The attaching of the attachment is mandatory" or just "attaching the attachment is mandatory" make sense, and feel more natural than "attachment of the attachment...", but they are a little repetitive. Depending on the context I'd prefer to describe what the attachment is, but without that you could say something like "connecting the attachment..." or "affixing the attachment...", depending on how exactly the attachment is attached.

Comment: "You must attatch an attatchment" works as well. Is this for an email? Are you referring to email attachments, like adding a downloadable file to an email?

Comment: Note, comments aren't "officially" part of the question. Your comment about the German equivalent really helps this question; please use the "edit" button to add it.